# Call api for every item in Observable<sourceitem[]> and "merge" it back to an Observable<targetitem[]>

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an Observable with items that are selected by the user. Every selected items is used as the source for an api call. And the results from the api call should be "merged" to an Observable.

The thing that I don't seem to get is how I merge the results back. I tried using the scan operator, but the "accumulator" only "grows".

I have this:

```js
import {
  Observable,
  Subject,
  of ,
  from
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  map,
  merge,
  flatMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';

function apiUri(albumId: String) {
  return `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${albumId}`
}


const albums$ = new Subject < String[] > ();

const responseStream = albums$.pipe(
  flatMap(albumIds => albumIds),
  flatMap(id => from(fetch(apiUri(id)))),
  flatMap(resp => resp.json()),
  /* I'm in the dark on how to "merge" it back into an Observable<String[]> */
);

responseStream.subscribe(resp => console.log(resp))
const randomCodes1 = ['5', '1', '3'];
albums$.next(randomCodes1);
```

Stackblitz link with running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-flatmap-galore?&file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that should allow you to create the `responseStream` that you are looking for.

```
const responseStream = albums$.pipe(
  map(albumIds => albumIds.map(id => from(fetch(apiUrl(id))).pipe(mergeMap(resp => resp.json())))),
  mergeMap(obsOfIds => forkJoin(obsOfIds)),
);
```

First of all, let's focus on `forkJoin`. You can pass to this operator an array of Observables, and this operator will return an Observable which emits when all Observables in the input array have emitted, and it will emit an array with the values emitted by each Observable in the input array.

This is what you are probably looking after. How to create the array of Observables that you need? This is what is performed by the first `map` operator.

Consider one thing when you look at that operator.

```
map(albumIds => albumIds.map(id => from(fetch(apiUrl(id))).pipe(mergeMap(resp => resp.json()))))
```

You are using 2 times `map`, but these are NOT the same `map`. The firs `map`, i.e. the most external one, is the `map` operator of Observable. The second `map`, i.e. the most internal one, is the `map` method of Array.

I have updated you stackblitz and it seems to work right.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense, and it works. I can't see the edited stackblitz, but I applied your code and it is exactly what I want. Thx!